# Android Management - How to send bulk request?

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

We have been using Android Management APIs to enroll devices in an enterprise and provide restricted environment to our users. We have a requirement where we need to bulk update all the devices by making a patch request using this API: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/patch

What I am looking for is that instead of sending requests one by one in an arbitrary fashion, is there any way I can send bulk requests and receive a response when all the devices are updated?

Note: I am already aware of how to do it one by one.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AndroidManagement.batch()` API to queue several requests for execution and reduce the connections your client makes. The now deprecated [Google EMM API documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/how-tos/batch) has more information about this.

Here's a pseudo example on how to create a batch request, queue a device patch call and execute the request thereafter.

```java
AndroidManagement amapi;
var batchRequest = amapi.batch();
amapi.enterprises().devices().patch(deviceName, content).queue(batchRequest, new JsonBatchCallback<>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device device, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
                        updateDevice(device);
                    }
                });

// queue another device patch request...

// execute all queued requests
batchRequest.execute();
```

Please note that if you want to do a bulk update in order to save on the [API usage limit](https://developers.google.com/android/management/usage), this will not help you. All requests in your batch will be counted separately when it comes to limits. There is no way around this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, let me try and see if it resolves the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more context about what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps what you want to do can be achieved with a policy. For example, to install an app on multiple devices, you could apply the same policy to those devices, and then add these lines to the policy:

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.google.samples.apps.iosched",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
  }
]
```

Regarding batch requests, here’s a sample code on how you can do batch requests in Android Management API.

```
def list_devices(request_id, response, exception):
    """Do something with the devices list response."""
    if exception is not None:
      # Do something with the exception.
      pass
    else:
      # Do something with the response.
      pass

get_device1 = androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().get(name=deviceName)
get_device2 = androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().get(name=deviceName)

batch = androidmanagement.new_batch_http_request();
batch.add(get_device1, list_devices)
batch.add(get_device2, list_devices)
batch.execute()
```

You may also check this [link](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/androidmanagement_v1.html#new_batch_http_request) for more details about new_batch_http_request.

Answer (score 0):

"You can use the batch() call on [AndroidEnterprise](https://blog.esper.io/gms-vs-non-gms-for-android) and execute bulk requests by calling BatchRequest.execute().
Please note, you are limited to 1000 calls in a single batch request, so if you need to make more calls than that, use multiple batch requests.

Here's the format you can refer to: [EMM API batch format](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/how-tos/batch#format-of-a-batch-request).
Along with an example: [EMM API batch example](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/how-tos/batch#example)."